# Python Nested Loop Working Weirdly

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a little problem in python, I wrote a nested loop, and when I executed my script, my second loop totally ignored the first loop...

```
    while 1 <= 5:
        for num in range(1, 10):
            print "test"
            i +=1
        k+=1
```

Comment: do you mean to say `i <= 5` ? ` 1 <= 5` is always `True`

Comment: "imbricate: arrange in an overlapping fashion like roof tiles" - I have learned a new word which is nothing to do with this code

Comment: Replace 'imbricated' by 'nested'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intend to use `k` for control of while loop. Change to this:

```
# you can give k or i a default value here as you like
k = 0
i = 0
while k <= 5:
    for num in range(1, 10):
        print "test"
        i +=1
    k+=1
```